# How to bypass clustering

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mern, node-cron

I have an express server and i trying to schedule a job to send automatic emails at a particular time(10:00 am in my case). And i am using node-cron package to schedule jobs.

But i am making use of clustering technique to increase my app performance due to which there are multiple workers created and running constantly. In my implementation i am creating workers equal to total cpu of my machine because of which i have 8 workers running at all times.

To perform a job i have to schedule the job in my server.js, due to which my job i running 8 times at that particular time but i want it to run only once at that particular time.

Below is my server.js:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const { errorHandler } = require("./middleware/errorMiddleware");
const connectDB = require("./config/db");
const cors = require("cors");
const cluster = require("cluster");
const totalCPUs = require("os").cpus().length;
const process = require("process");
var cron = require('node-cron');
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  // console.log(`Number of CPUs is ${totalCPUs}`);
  // console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);

  // Fork workers.
  for (let i = 0; i < totalCPUs; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  // if any worker dies fork a new worker
  cluster.on("exit", (worker, code, signal) => {
    // console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
    // console.log("Let's fork another worker!");
    cluster.fork();
  });

} else {

  connectDB();
  
  const app = express();
  
  const corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 204
  };

  app.use(cors(corsOptions))
  app.use(express.json());
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

  app.use("/api/admin", require("./routes/adminRoutes"));

  app.use(errorHandler);

 // This job run at 10:00 am every day
  cron.schedule('00 10 * * *', function() {
    console.log('send email');
  });
  
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Running on ${port}`);
  });
}
```

For this implementation i get `send email` 8 times in my console.

And if i take out that schedule out of `if else` block and keep that schedule at the very end of server.js like shown below then i get `send email` 9 times in my console

```
// same code as above

app.use(errorHandler);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Running on ${port}`);
  });
}

// This job run at 10:00 am every day
cron.schedule('00 10 * * *', function() {
    console.log('send email');
});
```

I tried few things but could not get the desired output. If there is any other way i can make use of then do tell me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, `cluster.isMaster` has been deprecated since v16 so you should be using `cluster.isPrimary` instead.

Then, you are putting the `cron.schedule()` code in the wrong place.  You are putting it in the clustered processes when is should be inside the `isPrimary` block so that it is only run once.

```
if (cluster.isPrimary) {
     cron.shedule(...); 
}
```